# Java swing jlabel.settext not immediate

Tags: java, netbeans

Good day, I am having an issue trying to get the Text on a label to say 'connecting ...' before the connection attempt starts and something else after it is connected. When the code below runs, the settext only displays once everything is complete. How can I get the first settext to display before the connection attempt?

```
private void buttonConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://domain.com:3306/tablename";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "userpassword";

        jLabel.setText("Connecting ...");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        jLabel.setText(con.getCatalog());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to connect to the database in your EventDispatcherThread which is basically the thread in charge of all the GUI items you have. The thread is taking it's time to connect to the database and once it completes (ie. it connects to the database) it updates your GUI.

You can use something like this to get it to work:

```
private void buttonConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jLabel.setText("Connecting ...");

        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                         String url = "jdbc:mysql://domain.com:3306/tablename";
                         String user = "username";
                         String password = "userpassword";



                         con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);        

                     } catch (SQLException ex) {
                         Logger.getLogger(connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
            }
        }
        )).start()        
}
```

I am assuming that `con` is some global variable. In this case, for it to be accessible within the `run()` method, it needs to be declared as `final`.

Comment: The `jLabel.setText(con.getCatalog());` is in the wrong place in your example. That should be done on the EDT after the connection has been made.

Comment: Thanks @npinti, this worked well - but I removed the .start() at the end.

Comment: -1, The invokeLater() method is used to add code to the EDT. When code is executing on the EDT the GUI can't repaint itself. Therefore by doing the database access on the EDT you are making the GUI non responsive. Instead the database access should be done on a separate Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @camickr: You are right, I have updated my answer. To my knowledge the invokeLater works on the EDT, but I've seen a couple of answers which recommended the invokeLater to do non UI stuff, so I was assuming that there was some standard or something... Anyways, I have fixed it so it should now be as it should.